# Page refresh issue on check in document

Tags: 2013, document-library

We have a document library SharePoint 2013 environment and user uploads their document in it. To edit document, they check out document and then open it in word and make changes and then check back in.

The issue is user need to refresh page back to get the file checked in. Is there some way we can refresh library page on check in from word?

Comment: I noticed the same problem: I defintely don't understand why, since it used to work (refresh) fine under SharePoint 2010! One of the many uncomprehensible "new features" of 2013! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the Ajax settings of the web part and set the refresh interval.

Go to edit page, click on the webpart and click on Edit web part. Under Ajax Options you have to enable asynchronous load and update.

Comment: Can you please add more details regarding how to do this?

Comment: @RobertLindgren see updated answer

Comment: I just want the page refresh when user check in document from word. If I set refresh interval, if its low (less than 3 minute) - the site will have over load and if its high (3 min or greater) - the user do not get updates.